# Github actions-Permission issue for for .Net self hosted runners

Tags: c#, github, .net-core, github-actions, cicd

Facing a permission issue while installing dotnet to default directory /usr/share/dotnet, after I tried specifying a DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR variable, the installation was successful.

**Initial error:**

> Run actions/setup-dotnet@v1.7.2
> /runner/_work/_actions/actions/setup-dotnet/v1.7.2/externals/install-dotnet.sh --version 6.0.419
> dotnet_install: Warning: Unable to locate zlib. Probable prerequisite missing; install zlib.
> dotnet-install: Downloading link: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/6.0.419/dotnet-sdk-6.0.419-linux-x64.tar.gz
> dotnet-install: Extracting zip from https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/6.0.419/dotnet-sdk-6.0.419-linux-x64.tar.gz
> cp: cannot create directory '/home/runner/.dotnet/host/fxr/6.0.27/': Permission denied
> Error: The process '/runner/_work/actions/actions/setup-dotnet/v1.7.2/externals/install-dotnet.sh' failed with exit code 1

- 
- 

**But the next step of dotnet restore failed because of a permission issue.**

*Error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
> '/home/runner/.dotnet/6.0.418.toolpath.sentinel' is denied.  --->
> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied    --- End of inner exception
> stack trace ---    at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo
> errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)    at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)    at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategy(FileStream fileStream, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize) at System.IO.File.Create(String path)    at Microsoft.Extensions.EnvironmentAbstractions.FileWrapper.CreateEmptyFile(String path)    at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.FileSystemExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<CreateIfNotExists>b__0() at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.FileAccessRetrier.RetryOnIOException(Action action)    at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.FileSystemExtensions.CreateIfNotExists(IFileSystem fileSystem, String filePath)    at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.FileSentinel.Create()    at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.DotnetFirstTimeUseConfigurer.Configure()   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ConfigureDotNetForFirstTimeUse(IFirstTimeUseNoticeSentinel firstTimeUseNoticeSentinel, IAspNetCertificateSentinel aspNetCertificateSentinel, IFileSentinel toolPathSentinel, Boolean isDotnetBeingInvokedFromNativeInstaller, DotnetFirstRunConfiguration dotnetFirstRunConfiguration, IEnvironmentProvider environmentProvider, Dictionary`2 performanceMeasurements)    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, TimeSpan
> startupTime, ITelemetry telemetryClient)    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args) Error: Process
> completed with exit code 1.

- 

Github Action

```
name: .NET

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]
permissions:
  contents: read
  id-token: write

jobs:
  deploy:
    # Our previously created self-hosted runner
    runs-on: [self-hosted, small, al2023]
    strategy:
      matrix:
        dotnet: ["6.0.x"]
    # A sequence of tasks that will execute as part of the job
    steps:
      - name: Setup Credentials
        uses: gha-setup-credentials@v2
      # Checks out repository so our job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup .NET Core SDK ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.7.2
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: dotnet restore

      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
```